# How to select records with no matches in the foreign table (Left outer join)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have one table that holds my ressources:

### Ressource | Ressource-ID

And a table that holds the associations

### Ressource-ID | Employee-ID

How to select the ressources of an Employee that are available, i.e. not in the association table?

I've tried this, but it's not working:

```
select r.ress, r.ress_id
FROM Ressource r
LEFT outer JOIN Ressource_Employee_Association a ON r.ress_id = a.ress_id
WHERE a.emp_id = 'ID00163efea66b' and a.ress_id IS NULL
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: I think your query/data logic is fundamentally flawed, or you're not explaining the problem well enough.  I don't understand how you can select "the resource of an employee that is available" when the state of the resource being available is represented by the resource not being in the association table, but the availability of the resource to an employee is represented by a record being present in the same table.

Comment: In less words: "You can't use this resource because you don't have permission" but when you add permission "You can't use this resource because it's currently in use."  Certainly correct me if I'm wrong - I'm happy to help, but it seems that your problem is that your table structure is not thought out well enough, and not that you can't figure out the query.  PS. you spelled "Resource" wrong.

Comment: Jim, the existing ressources are stored in the ressource table. When I assign a ressource to a user I create a record consisting of the ressource-id and user-id in the associations table. So when seven ressources exist in total and the user has three records in the associations table, then 4 ressources are avaiable to him. The alternative would be to create seven records per employee in the associations table and adding a field called available. But that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I posted an answer which should satisfy your problem, look below (: --  It doesn't use sub-queries like everyone elses solution, so it should yield better performance, but I'd run an explain on all the prospective solutions to find out which is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing my above comments, and looking at the proposed solutions: I think I've got some more understanding of what you are trying to do.

Assuming you have unlimited quantity of resources in your resources table, you want to select the un-assigned resources per employee (based on their non-existence for any specific employee in the resource association table).

In order to accomplish this (and get a comprehensive list of employees) you'll need a 3rd table, in order to reference the complete list of employees.  You'll also need to `CROSS JOIN` all of the resources onto the list of employees (assuming every employee has access to every resource), then you `LEFT JOIN` (`LEFT OUTER JOIN` whatever) your association list onto the query where the `resource_id` and `employee_id` match the `resource_id` in the `resources` table, and the `employee_id` in the `employees` table (respectively). THEN you add your where clause that filters out all the records that assign an employee to a resource.  This leaves you with the resources that are available to the employee, which they also do not have signed out. This is convoluted to say, so hopefully the query sheds more light:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee, r.res_id, r.res

FROM employees e
CROSS JOIN resources r
LEFT JOIN assigned_resources ar
    ON ar.employee_id = e.employee_id AND r.res_id = ar.res_id

WHERE ar.res_id IS NULL
```

If you don't have an `employees` table, you can accomplish the same by using the assigned resources table, but you will be limited to selecting employees who already have some resources allocated.  You'll need to add a `GROUP BY` query because of the possible existence of multiple employee definitions in the association table.  Here's what that query would look like:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, r.res_id, r.res

FROM assigned_resources e
CROSS JOIN resources r
LEFT JOIN assigned_resources ar
    ON ar.employee_id = e.employee_id AND r.res_id = ar.res_id

WHERE ar.res_id IS NULL

GROUP BY e.employee_id, r.res_id
```

Comment: After a comment from the OP, this was my guess too.   (Except that I used NOT EXISTS rather than a LEFT JOIN, the answers are the same, so hopefully we're right!)

Comment: The only issue with the `NOT EXISTS` is that it uses a sub-query.  These can get *really* expensive!  But, `CROSS JOIN`s aren't exactly cheap either...so he'll need to do some performance testing (:

Comment: Last I saw Oracle11g processes it as an anti-semi-join rather than a full-blown correlated sub-query.  As for the CROSS JOIN, the OP seems to want a view where he can specify a single user_id, in which case the CROSS JOIN can all but be ignored.

Comment: I'm not sure what the DMBS the OP is using, and I'm not very familiar with the query optimizer for Oracle; so I won't pretend to understand the how Oracle optimizes queries.  As for the cross join, it's required to compile a list of all resources for all employees.  Anyway, the point is moot if we're both incorrect as to our understanding of what @Thomas is after, haha.

Comment: The question is tagged as Oracle11g :)

Comment: Thanks Jim. Just for your information and/or satisfaction your query takes 60ms vs 110ms Dems NOT EXISTS query. Yet, onedaywhen's MINUS query is as fast as yours. Too bad I can't add the ressource name to his MINUS query. The compactness and speed of the MINUS query is appealing.

Answer (score 1):

The WHERE clause is applied after the LEFT JOIN.  This means that you are currently trying to get results where there is NO matching record in Ressource_Employee_Association, but where the `emp_id` equals `'ID00163efea66b'`.

But if there is no matching record, how can `emp_id` be anything other than `NULL`?

One option is to move part of the WHERE clause into the join...

```
SELECT
  r.ress, r.ress_id
FROM
  Ressource r
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  Ressource_Employee_Association a
    ON r.ress_id = a.ress_id
    AND a.emp_id = 'ID00163efea66b'
WHERE
  a.ress_id IS NULL
```

This will list all resources that are not associated to employee `'ID00163efea66b'`.

**EDIT**

Your comment implies that what you want is...
- A view listing all employees
- For each employee list each resource that they DON'T have

This requires an extra table listing all of your employees.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Employee
CROSS JOIN
  Ressource
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Ressource_Employee_Association
               WHERE emp_id  = Employee.id
                 AND ress_id = Ressource.id)
```

Comment: That would be fine, but I want to use this statement to create a view. So I can't use fixed ids in the statement.

Comment: @Thomas - I've reformulated your question in my answer, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
select r.ress, r.ress_id
from resource r
where not exists 
(
    select 1 from ressource_emplyee_association a 
    where a.emp_id = '...' and a.ress_id = r.ress_id
)
```

**EDIT**
Before that I had the following, but changed it according to the comments below:

```
select r.ress, r.ress_id
from resource r
where not exists 
(
    select top 1 1 from ressource_emplyee_association a 
    where a.emp_id = '...' and a.ress_id = r.ress_id
)
```

Comment: `EXISTS` doesn't need a `TOP 1` *(which is fortunate as it isn't Oracle syntax)*, that's almost the point of `EXISTS`...  But yes, other than that it should seem to be what the OP asked for :)

Comment: Really? I thought that in general the inner select might return a whole bunch of records and using `top` would cause the inner select to be much quicker, so the entire `where` clause would be evaluated faster?

Comment: `EXISTS` is nearly always optimised to stop after a single match.  Especially in SQL Server (Top) and Oracle (As tagged by the OP).

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected Oracle doesn't know select top 1 1

Comment: OK. Didn't know that - thanks for the hint! I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Ressource
 WHERE ress_id IN (
                   SELECT ress_id, 
                     FROM Ressource 
                   MINUS
                   SELECT ress_id
                     FROM Ressource_Employee_Association 
                    WHERE emp_id = 'ID00163efea66b'
                  );
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Can I add ress, ress_id somehow to see the ressource name in plain text? I tried and it says ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns

Comment: Put this in a subquery (CTE, derived table, VIEW, whatever) then (semi) join back to the `Ressource` table.